# multiple undefined qty inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Allright, i'm creating a little system so customers can place online their order with us. We will receive by email the order and process it in our own system. They will place a order on a page, with some basic information they need to fill in. After that they need to fill in their order. Each order line has 3 fields. Partnumber, Quantity and Price. Price will be a readonly and wont be submitted. Only showing the price.

I want to create with jQuery a small input field and a plus icon. When you type in 10 and click on the plus icon, their will be 10 extra rows of 3 fields. This i didnt create yet, but now you know how i want to work.

The problem is how will i handle the form? The fields are required, but i would like when just a line is empty, it wont be submitted or ignored in PHP. So i only want to check the forms that has been filled in. Sometimes it will be 4 lines, sometimes 20, sometimes 100 lines. So the qty of inputs we dont know. How should i create the form names?

Here some PHP:

```
if(toxInput::exists()){
```

if(toxToken::check(toxInput::get('token'))){

```
$toxValidate = new toxValidate();
$toxValidation = $toxValidate->check('$_POST', array(
        'po'            => array('required' => TRUE),
        'date'      => array('required' => TRUE),
        'bo'            => array('required' => TRUE),
        'remarks'   => array('required' => TRUE)
));

if($toxValidate->passed()){
    echo 'Run insert';
}
```

}
}

Here a screenshot of the form how it looks: http://prntscr.com/eigfc2

Here the HTML of the form:

```
<p><h2>Items</h2></p>
                        <p class="order">
                        <label  style="margin-left:20px;">Partnumber:</label><br />
                        <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="order" >
                        <label style="margin-left:20px">Qty</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                        <p class="order">
                        <label style="margin-left:20px">Price</label><br>
                        <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly /><br>
                      </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                    <input type="text" style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                    <input type="text"  style="margin-left:16px;" class="text small" placeholder="Price" readonly />
                  </p>

                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo toxToken::generate(); ?>">
```

I know about the margins, needs to be nice in a class but was for testing.

Comment: *"How should i create the form names?"* - The input field names should all be the same, and treated as an array on the PHP side. (That is, all the Part Number fields should have the same `name` as each other, and all of the Quantity fields should have the same `name` as each other.) I'm not a PHP guy, but I think if you name them like `Qty[]` that works with PHP? One way to ignore empty lines is on submit use jQuery to loop over the rows and either delete them or remove their `name` attribute so that they don't get submitted. But you should be validating the data on the PHP side either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this up for you to show how to append input fields, which I would use an array for.  I'm only using one input variable (myOrder) but you can use as many as you want.  Much easier to validate in a for loop.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myButton").click(function(){
       // create loop to add ten inputs if needed
       $("#myOrderForm").append('Product: <input type="text"  
                name="myOrder[]" /><br>');
        });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Buy another product" />

<form method="post" action="addInput.php">
<div id="myOrderForm">  //input tags here
Product: <input type="text" name="myOrder[]" /><br>
Product: <input type="text" name="myOrder[]" /><br>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Place Order">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The php file addInput.php

```
<?php
$myOrders=$_POST["myOrder"];
for ($i=0; $i<count($myOrders); $i++)
    { 
     // validate each array member with if (empty($myOrders[$i]))
     // do something
     echo $myOrders[$i]."<br>"; // echo just for example
     }

?>
```